# MDX Syntax to retrieve Specific Dates

Tags: mdx, pyramid-analytics

I am building some reports in Pyramid Analytics. I created a custom set and tried to write a MDX query which will retrieve the first day of the first month for the first three quarters of the previous year, selected in the slicer. i.e.
If I choose in my slicer 2017, I expect to see the following in the body of the report: Jan 1st 2016, April 1st 2016 and July 1st 2016. These will change according to the selection in the slicer.

I only got as far as the syntax below, which only returns first day of the first month of the first quarter of the previous year i.e. Jan 1st 2016

```
[Policy - Inception Date].[Calendar Hierarchy].[!@NewPar@!].PREVMEMBER.FIRSTCHILD.FIRSTCHILD.FIRSTCHILD
```

Note:Newpar = Parameter 
Can you please help with the correct syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: we'll need to know the structure of your date dimension - what user hierarchies & attribute hierarchies, from the date dimension,  do you have visible/available in Pyramid ?

Comment: did you create via "create custom member" or "create custom set" ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the structure of your Date dimension I'm having to use some guess work but I've made the following in Pyramid and it works fine against our cube:

```
Generate
(
  Head  //<<<this will get the first 3 quarters
  (
    Descendants
    (
      {[Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[!@aYear@!].PrevMember}   //<<<this will get the previous year
     ,[Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Quarter]
    )
   ,3
  )
 ,Head  //<<<this will get the first day of each of the quarters found in the first argument of the generate function
  (
    Descendants
    (
      [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CurrentMember
     ,[Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day]
    )
   ,1
  )
)
```

Here is the result with the year parameter in the top left:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. 
I eventually went out about it a different way:

{
[Policy - Inception Date].[Calendar Hierarchy].[!@NewPar@!].PREVMEMBER.FIRSTCHILD.FIRSTCHILD.FIRSTCHILD  
,[Policy - Inception Date].[Calendar Hierarchy].[!@NewPar@!].PREVMEMBER.FIRSTCHILD.NEXTMEMBER.FIRSTCHILD.FIRSTCHILD
,[Policy - Inception Date].[Calendar Hierarchy].[!@NewPar@!].PREVMEMBER.FIRSTCHILD.LEAD(2).FIRSTCHILD.FIRSTCHILD
}

Comment: no worries King George - glad you found some sort of solution.